# How to adjust verbose-ibid citation style to requirements of an author

Tags: biblatex

I’m editing a book in social science and I need to adjust style of footnotes and bibliography to the demands of the author.
I need almost full citation in footnotes. So I started to use biblatex (with biber) with `style=verbose-ibid`, as it is the closest style that I could find. But it still needs some improvements/modifications.
By using it i get something like this:

> 1. Miralles Martínez, Pedro y Rivero Gracia, Pilar, “Propuestas de
>      innovación para la enseñanza de la historia en educación Infantil”.
>      En: Revista Electrónica Interuniversitaria de Formación del
>      Profesorado (REIFOP) 15.1 (2012), páginas 81-90.
> 2. Barabas, Alicia M, “Multiculturalismo, pluralismo cultural e
>      interculturalidad en el contexto de América Latina: la presencia de
>      los pueblos originarios”. En: Configurações 14 (2014).
> 3. Prats, J. y col., Enseñanza y aprendizaje de la Historia en la
>      Educación Básica. México: Secretaría de Educación Pública y
>      Universidad Pedagógica Nacional., 2011.
> 4. Sousa Ramos, Boaventura de, “La hora de los invisibles”. En: Sumak
>      Kawsay. Buen Vivir y cambios civilizatorios. Editado por
>      (coordinadora), Irene León. Quito: Fundación de Estudios, Acción y
>      Participación Social, 2010, páginas 13-25

while I need this:

> 1. Miralles Martínez, Pedro, y Rivero Gracia, Pilar, “Propuestas de
>      innovación para la enseñanza de la historia en Educación Infantil”,
>      Revista Electrónica Interuniversitaria de Formación del Profesorado
>      (REIFOP), 15(1), 2012, pp. 81-90
> 2. Barabas, Alicia M., “Multiculturalismo, pluralismo cultural e interculturalidad en el contexto de América Latina: la presencia de los pueblos
>      originarios”, Configurações 14, 2014, pp. xxxx
> 3. Prats, J. y col., Enseñanza y aprendizaje de la Historia en la Educación Básica, México, Secretaría de Educación Pública, 2011, pp. 158-160.
> 4. Sousa Ramos, Boaventura de, “La hora de los invisibles”, en León, Irene
>      (ed.),  Sumak Kawsay. Buen Vivir y cambios civilizatorios, Quito,
>      Fundación de Estudios, Acción y Participación Social, 2010, pp.
>      13-25

My desired format for footnotes and bibliography is:

1. For articles: Name of Author(s), Title of article in quotation mark. Title of journal in italics without quotation mark (without italics and no “[in:]” before it)” Year, vol. (no.) number in parentheses
2. For books: Name of Author(s), *Title in italics*, city, editorial, year, pp.
3. For incollection: Name of Author(s), “Title of chapter in quotation mark”,  en Name of Editor(s) and after it (ed./eds. in parenthesis), *BookTitle in italics*, City, publisher, Year of publications, pp.

In sum, the above mentioned style has all the elements that I need but they order and formatting needs to be a little bit changed.
SC
Main document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true, autopunct=true, babel=hyphen,hyperref=false,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
bibwarn=true, %
bibencoding=inputenc, % (auto, ascii, inputenc, <encoding>)
isbn=false,%
url=false,%
doi=false,%
eprint=false,%  
firstinits=false,% Initialien Erzeugen
}% 
\addbibresource{Biblio_esmeraldas2.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last} %primero el apellido del autor
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}%coma despues del nombre del autor
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start using `biblatex-ext` to make it easier to move the editor name before the title and change the punctuation.

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes} % try spanish=mexican

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-verbose-ibid,
  sorting=nyt, sortcites=true,
  innamebeforetitle=true, articlein=false,
  isbn=false, url=false, doi=false, eprint=false,
  autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\locpubdelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  page  = {p\adddot},
  pages = {pp\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}
ipsum\autocite{gaonkar:in,pines}
dolor\autocite{nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> Aksın, Özge y col., «Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions», *J. Organomet. Chem.*, 691.13, 2006, pp. 3027-3036.
>
> Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar, «On Alternative Modernities» en Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar (ed.), *Alternative Modernities*, Durham y London, Duke University Press, 2001, pp. 1-23.
>
> Nussbaum, Martha, *Aristotle’s «De Motu Animalium»*, Princeton, Princeton University Press, 1978.
>
> Pines, Shlomo, «The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and Maimonides» en Twersky, Isadore (ed.), *Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature*, Cambridge, Mass., Harvard University Press, 1979, pp. 82-109.
>
> Sigfridsson, Emma y Ryde, Ulf, «Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments», *Journal of Computational Chemistry*, 19.4, 1998, pp. 377-395.

[image: Screenshot of the references]